# Subtracting point values from raster maps in QGIS

Tags: raster, qgis-3, point, mapping

I have point values (x,y,z) and a raster map with z-values. I would like to subtract the z-values of the raster map from the z-values of the points.

The resulting data has to be point data (x of point values, y of point values, z of point values minus z of raster map values).

How do I do it? By hand won't be an option because there are way too many points. I use QGIS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that using the following steps:

1. Use `Sample raster values` to extract the raster values to the point locations

[image]

2. Add a new field of numeric type (float, for example) name it `Subtract` or the name you like to store the subtracted values.
3. Finally, use field calculator to subtract the values retrieved in step 1 from z values of point data.

*Note*: Make sure that both raster and point data have the same projection (CRS) before starting the whole process.